# compare 2nd column of two or more files and print union of all files

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have four tab separated files 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt. Each having following format

```
89  ABI1    0.19
93  ABL1    0.15
94  ABL2    0.07
170 ACSL3   0.21
```

I want to compare 2nd column of all files and print union (based on 2nd column) into new file, like following:

```
       1.txt    2.txt   3.txt   4.txt
ABL2    0.07    0.01    0.11    0.009
AKT1    0.31    0.05    0.05    0.017
AKT2    0.33    0.05    0.01    0.004
```

How is it possible in awk?
I tried following but this only compares first columns,

```
awk  'NR==FNR {h[$1] = $0; next} {print $1,h[$1]}' OFS="\t" 2.txt 1.txt
```

but when I change it to compare 2nd column it doesn't work

```
awk  'NR==FNR {h[$2] = $0; next} {print $1,h[$2]}' OFS="\t" 2.txt 1.txt
```

Also this only works on two files at a time.

Is there any way to do it on four files by comparing 2nd column in awk?

Comment: can you post the contents for `2.txt` and `3.txt` ?

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` on *sorted* input files, and assuming a shell that understands process substitutions with `<(...)` (I've used a copy of the data that you provided for every input file, just adding a line at the top for identification, this is the `AAA` line):

```
$ join <( join -1 2 -2 2 -o 0,1.3,2.3 1.txt 2.txt ) \
       <( join -1 2 -2 2 -o 0,1.3,2.3 3.txt 4.txt )
AAA 1 2 3 4
ABI1 0.19 0.19 0.19 0.19
ABL1 0.15 0.15 0.15 0.15
ABL2 0.07 0.07 0.07 0.07
ACSL3 0.21 0.21 0.21 0.21
```

There are three joins here. The first two to be performed are the ones in `<(...)`.  The first of these join the first two files, while the second join the last two files.  The result of one of these joins looks like

```
AAA 1 2
ABI1 0.19 0.19
ABL1 0.15 0.15
ABL2 0.07 0.07
ACSL3 0.21 0.21
```

The option `-o 0,1.3,2.3` means "output the join field along with field 3 from both files".  `-1 2 -2 2` means "use field 2 of each file as join field (rather than field 1)".

The outermost `join` takes the two results and performs the final join that produces the output.

If the input files are not sorted on the join field:

```
$ join <( join -1 2 -2 2 -o 0,1.3,2.3 <(sort -k2,2 1.txt) <(sort -k2,2 2.txt) ) \
       <( join -1 2 -2 2 -o 0,1.3,2.3 <(sort -k2,2 3.txt) <(sort -k2,2 4.txt) )
```